# ActiveStorage get dirty object stating if an image as changed

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I would like to know if an image has changed on an ActiveRecord model object so I can perform other functions but don't see anything available to know this.

I.E.

```
object.image.changed? or object.image_changed? or object.changed?
```

Answer (score 11):

If you would like to know before the object has saved:

`object.attachment_changes.any?`

If you would like to know after the changes having been committed, the only solution I've found so far is to check the blob:

`object.image.blob.saved_changes?`